# How to initialize a type with an underlying string value in go?

Tags: go

This works:

```
type T string
var t T = "hello"
```

http://play.golang.org/p/275jQ4ixvp

But this fails with `cannot use s (type string) as type T in assignment`

```
type T string
s := "world"
var t T = s
```

http://play.golang.org/p/vm3mC5ltcE

How can I make this second situation work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the string to the correct type [[conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)]

http://play.golang.org/p/dkavI_QgPb

```
s := "world"
t := T(s)
fmt.Println(t)
```